# Keep getting index out of range

Tags: java, char, boolean, double, indexoutofrangeexception

I am making a program that counts the words in a sentence. Spaces do not count and punctuation does not count. I am using a module that will take in an input and will output an answer. But do not worry about that because I do not think it is the reason why my program is printing out this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: 
String index out of range: 11
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at WordCount.main(WordCount.java:20)
```

```
public class WordCount{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println("Please enter sentence");
        String sentence= IO.readString();

        System.out.println("Please enter minimum word length");
        double minword= IO.readInt();

        String word;
        int wordletter=0;
        int wordcount= 0;

        int count= -1;
        int end= sentence.length();

        do{
            count++;
            char space= sentence.charAt(count);

            if(Character.isLetter(space)){
                boolean cut= Character.isSpaceChar(space);
                if(cut== true)
                    word=sentence.substring(0,count);
                    count= 0;
                    wordletter= word.length();
                    end= end- wordletter;

                    if(wordletter< minword){
                        ;
                    }else{
                        wordcount= wordcount+1;
                    }
                }else{
                    ;
                }
            }else{
                ;
            }
        }while(count!= end);

    IO.outputIntAnswer(wordcount);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`char space= sentence.charAt(count);` is causing the exception because your loop condition is running too many times. You want less than instead of not equals to for the while condition

```
while (count - 1 < end);
```

The minus 1 is required because you have constructed your loop in a strange way, I would normally go for something like this:

```
int end= sentence.length();
count = -1;
while (++count < end) {

}
```

Alternatively, and even better. Use a `for` loop.

```
int end = sentence.length();
for (int i = 0; i < end; i++ {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you copied it correctly? (removed any count++ from the body). It should run from 0 to sentence.length() - 1.

Comment: yes I did. Before I used the do while loop I used a for loop and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that an array has `array.length` elements whose indexes are `0, 1, ... array.length - 1`.  You code (as written) is going to try indexes `0, 1, ... array.length`.

Think about the condition you are using terminating the loop.

---

But that is not sufficient to fix your program.  I can see at least two more bugs.  Since this is obviously a learning exercise, I recommend that you find and fix them yourself ... 'cos that is an important skill you need to develop.  I recommend that you run your program using your IDE's debugger, and "single step" through your code to see what it is doing.